# Defining a function before and after main() in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,x,m,i;
    int sqroot,prime;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&m);
        if(isprime(m))
            printf("NO\n");
        else if(isprime(sqrt(m)))
                printf("NO\n");
        else
                printf("YES\n");
    }

}

int isprime(int num)
{
    int i=2,flag=1;
    for(;i<sqrt(num);i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }

    }
    return flag;
}
```

This is C code to find the number which has 2 factors and 3 factors. I faced a problem when we put prime function before `main()`, it gives the wrong result. But whenever we put prime function after `main()` it gives the right result.

Comment: What happens if you declare your function before calling it, by giving the prototype `int isprime(int num)` before main() ?

Comment: @Anshul Raj  Show the difference in the results.

Comment: Are you sure you get the WRONG result with function BEFORE main()? That is acrtually a correct way of doing this (the other being having a prototype there). The problem would hence have to be very subtle...

Comment: Sqrt can be imprecise, better to add 1 to it to ensure that you don't misclassify squared primes!

Comment: Comparing integers to floating point values is risky, which you do here `i<sqrt(num)`. As long as the numbers are not very high, `i*i<num` would be better. With potentially high numbers go with Antti comment.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Do you agree that if that helps the error is quite interesting? I.e. that cleaning up the call before definition problem causes it to become visible, while with the function late it works.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: under IEEE754 `sqrt` is required to yield the best `double` possible, although not all platforms stick to that faithfully, despite purportedly being IEEE754. Personally I prefer `1LL * i * i <= num`. Note you nee `<=` else your algorithm gives false results for prime squares. Simply adding 1 seems crude to me.

Comment: @Yunnosch I do, but I doubt it to be the case here. `int isprime(int num)` should work with implicit function definition/default argument promotions as is.

Comment: I've read this question several times and I still do not know what the program is **supposed to do**. If it is supposed to tell if *a number that has more than one  distinct prime factor*, then it is very very wrong and possibly reordering the function definition cannot change that.

Comment: @Bathsheba When `i!=0`, `i <= num/i` has advantages over `1LL * i * i <= num`: No overflow possible, "low" CPU cost as later code has `num%i` and good compilers compute those for about the price of one.

Comment: You **must** declare any function before you call it. If your compiler lets you omit a declaration, then either it is too old and should be thrown away, or [you are not paying attention to diagnostic messages](https://ideone.com/iX2OM2). You always should enable all warnings and treat them as errors, for the sake of your own sanity. Anyway you need to post your result, as opposed to just telling us that it is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> I faced a problem when we put prime function before main(), it gives the wrong result

`isprime(int num)` in functionally wrong.

`for(;i<sqrt(num);i++)` should be more like `for(;i<=sqrt(num);i++)`.  `<` vs. `<=`.  [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738727/defining-a-function-before-and-after-main-in-c?noredirect=1#comment101916898_57738727)

With some other fixes/improvements:
* `i <= num/i` does not overflow nor incur potential problems due to complexities/imprecision of `i<=sqrt(num)`.<sup>1</sup>
* Often `num/i` with nearby `num%i` is efficiently computed via a good compiler as one.
* OP code dies on `isprime(any_negative)`.

```
int isprime(int num) {
  if (num <= 3) {    // Handle negatives,0,1,2,3
    return num >= 2; // Only 2,3 are prime
  }
  int i;
  for (i = 3; i <= num/i; i += 2) {
    if (num%i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

> we put prime function after main() it gives the right result.

`isprime(sqrt(m))` does not know that `isprime(int)` requires an `int` argument and so does not convert the `double` result of `sqrt()` to `int` resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB).  Code might "work", might not.

Code could *declare* the function before `main()` with

```
int isprime(int num);

int main()
  ....
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  Complexities include:

- `sqrt()` may be weakly implemented and the result just under the desired value.  `sqrt(121)` may yield `10.999999999999999...` rather than the needed `11.0` [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738727/defining-a-function-before-and-after-main-in-c?noredirect=1#comment101916699_57738727).  Code could use `lround(sqrt())` to compensate.  Yet better to avoid `double` math for an *integer* problem.
- `double` may not exactly represent large `int` values say when `int` is 64-bit.  Then `sqrt()` may begin with a rounded down argument, leading to a too small result for the compare.
- A common compiler `for(;i<sqrt(num);i++)` may not know `sqrt()` lacks side effects and so call `sqrt()` repeatedly - no so efficient.  Code could call once ahead of the loop.